# jQuery UI draggable not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

jQuery draggable not working in chrome

Code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="type/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( ".drag" ).draggable();
});
</script>

<div class="drag">draggable</div>
```

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Nothing is wrong with that even, here, seems not so useful for other readers

Answer (score 1):

[JS FIDDLE Test](http://jsfiddle.net/pCgZx/)
Try this. In my browser dargging works correctly. Working in your browser? If not working, then you wrong plugged jqueryui library.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

window.onload = function(){
    $( "#drag" ).draggable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, code is correct but Chrome extension adBlocker blocking draggable function. Just uninstall adBlocker and reset chrome.

Comment: adBlocker blocks UI draggable, how that?

Comment: You asked a question and posted answer. Are we moving on?

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't how but now I worked on it 3 hours why this code not working in chrom but in IE it works. So I uninstalled adBlocker restart Chrome and then draggable works.