# jquery ui sortable not working in Chrome

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, jquery-ui-sortable, web-component, shadow-dom

I am using jquery UI's sortable to sort a list with 16 items. I am using jQuery UI inside a Polymer custom element on Chrome but I am unable to drag elements around in Chrome. This works fine in Edge and FF. Can this be related to the native implementation on web components in Chrome (shadow-dom to be specific?). I am using a template to stamp out the draggable items. Here is the code snippet.

```
<link rel="import" href="../shared-libs.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../shared-styles/shared-w3css.html">

<dom-module id="nn-grid">
    <template>

        <style include="shared-w3css"></style>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* styles go here */
        </style>

        <ul id="sortable">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tiles}}">
            <li class$="ui-state-default w3-col s3 {{item.color}}"><span>{{item.number}}</span></li>
          </template>
        </ul>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: "nn-grid",

        ready : function() {
            this.tiles = [
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-pink', number: 1},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-blue', number: 2},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-green', number: 3},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-yellow', number: 4},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-blue', number: 5},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-green', number: 6},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-yellow', number: 7},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-pink', number: 8},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-green', number: 9},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-yellow', number: 10},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-pink', number: 11},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-blue', number: 12},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-pink', number: 13},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-blue', number: 14},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-blank ui-state-moving', number: ''},
                {moving: '', color: 'tile-green', number: 16}
            ];
        },

        attached : function () {

            $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
            $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

        }
      });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014994/jquery-ui-draggable-not-working-in-chrome) link but no luck. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: is there an error reported in the console?

Comment: works ok for me in Chrome and Firefox. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/dsk5azcj/)